# SQL Server Agent Job Step "Run As" dropdown

Tags: sql-server

When creating a job step in SQL Server 2008 R2 Agent, the third dropdown in the General page is "Run as:" - but this is empty, and seems to always be empty! What is it for?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Run As" is so that you can specify a proxy account to run the particular step as.  The proxy account defines the security context that a job step can run as.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189064.aspx for more info on sql server agent proxies.